# Translucent lines inconsistently showing as opaque

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've got a bunch of curved translucent `Line`s stacked on top of each other inside a rotating container. The opacity set on the lines seems to only be working some of the time, tho.

[image: Sometimes works, sometimes doesn't]

I can't actually figure out what's making it work in some instances but not others.

Here's a stripped down example:
http://jsfiddle.net/sccottt/ok7k41c5/

The meat of the code is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < LINE_COUNT; i++) {

    var curve       = new THREE.QuadraticBezierCurve3();
        curve.v0    = randomV3();
        curve.v1    = randomV3();
        curve.v2    = randomV3();

    var geom        = new THREE.Geometry();

    for (var j = 0; j <= CURVE_STEPS; j++) {
        var perc            = j / CURVE_STEPS;
        geom.vertices[j]    = curve.getPoint(perc);
    }

    var material    = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
        color: Math.random() * 0xffffff,
        linewidth: 10,
        transparent: true,
        opacity: 0.25
    });

    var line        = new THREE.Line(geom, material);

    _wrap.add(line);

}
```

Am I doing something wrong that's preventing the lines from always overlapping with transparency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `depthWrite: false` to your material.

http://jsfiddle.net/ok7k41c5/1/

Comment: Aw yiss. That's it! Thanks so much Matthias.